# npm mv module with async/await

Tags: node.js, file, async-await, mv

is there a way to use the mv npm module in an async/await manner? not with a callback as provided in docs.
Or is there any other module that does the same job? thanks

```
var mv = require('mv');
 
mv('source/file', 'dest/file', function(err) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `promisify` function of the `util` package

```js
const util = require('util');
const mv = require('mv');

const mvPromise = util.promisify(mv);

await mvPromise('source/file', 'dest/file');
```